# Word 2010 Content Controls New Line

Tags: c#, ms-word, newline, word-2010, word-contentcontrol

I am populating a content control in word 2010 with some text. I can't get my text to go on a new line. I have tried '\n' ,'\r', Environment.NewLine and it still appears on one line.

Any ideas what I should be using

Comment: I have tried plain and rich text

Comment: did the answer below answer your question?

Comment: did the answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you may need to enable `MultiLine = True` for the CC. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.contentcontrol.multiline(v=VS.90).aspx

If you've already done that, see [Microsoft Word Document Controls not accepting carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349090/microsoft-word-document-controls-not-accepting-carriage-returns) for a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
private static Run InsertFormatRun(Run run, string[] formatText)
        {
            foreach (string text in formatText)
            {
                run.AppendChild(new Text(text));
                RunProperties runProps = run.AppendChild(new RunProperties());
                Break linebreak = new Break();
                runProps.AppendChild(linebreak);
            }
                return run;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VBA, what you are searching for is

```
vbNewLine
```

which will insert a full line break.